# Changing time zone in appengine admin logs

Tags: google-app-engine

Is there a way to change the timz zone of the appengine admin logs?
My problem is that when I read the admin log, I always have to compute the time of the error in my local time zone.
I'd like the logs to display either my local time or to say "X hours ago".

How can I do?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not possible yet, there are two features requests about it:

- http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=76
- http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=734

The only work around that I can offer you will be to explicit log your local time.

Answer (score 3):

Have a look to [this](http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/47857) Greasemonkey extension.

> It adjusts Google App Engine's log
>   timezone(PST) to your local timezone

Answer (score 2):

Update: This is now possible by changing the value of "Time Zone" inside the "Jump to date" menu in the Google Cloud Console Logs Viewer.